# Iterate over an array and fill empty adjacent spots in array

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have created an multi dimensional array of empty strings with some row/columns being filled with a letter. Goal is to to fill the adjacent empty slots where the letters are found with that letter. I have most of array filling but I also want to count how many times loops occur to fill array.

This is in python 3 using numpy module only.
It keeps going out of range of index or I get infinite loops.

```
import numpy as np

letter_spots=[[3,0],[3,4],[1,3]]

A_array= np.zeros([5,5],str)

for lists in letter_spots:

    A_array[lists[0]][lists[1]]='A'


for row in range(A_array.shape[0]):
     for column in range(A_array.shape[1]):
        if A_array[row][column]=='A':
            if column+1 < A_array.shape[0]:
                if  A_array[row][column+1]=='':
                    A_array[row][column+1]='A'
            if column>0:
                if A_array[row][column - 1] == '':
                   A_array[row][column - 1] = 'A'
            if row + 1 < A_array.shape[0]:
                if A_array[row + 1][column] == '':
                   A_array[row + 1][column] = 'A'
            if row > 0:
                if A_array[row - 1][column] == '':
                   A_array[row - 1][column] = 'A'
```

Start array:

```
[['' '' '' '' '']
['' '' '' 'A' '']
['' '' '' '' '']
['A' '' '' '' 'A']
['' '' '' '' '']]
```

Current End Array:

```
[['' '' '' 'A' 'A']
['' '' 'A' 'A' 'A']
['A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A']
['A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A']
['A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A']]
```

Expected End Array:

```
[['A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A']
['A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A']
['A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A']
['A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A']
['A' 'A' 'A' 'A' 'A']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use where

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array([2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2])
print np.where(array1==0, 1, array1)
```

Comment: Issue is I want to track how many times the loop occurs to fill array, if I only wanted to fill array all at once np.where would work fine.